# How to change the contents of multiple XML files

Tags: xml, text-size

I have 800 xml files and I want to edit the contents of these files. For example change the value "LEFT" to "RIGHT". But it is very difficult to change so may files manually.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this automatically, via code or software?

Comment: With any code language, you will have to create a loop and read each XML file and do an update on the value you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a simple text replacement, you can use `sed`:

```
sed -e s/LEFT/RIGHT/g -i .bak *.xml
```

This will save backups with names ending with `.bak`. If you do not want to make backups, change `-i .bak` to `-i ''`.